# How to write this more compact

Tags: c++, string, integer, hex, buffer

I am trying to convert a char buffer into multiple int variables. This is what i got so far after a day of trying.

```
ZeroMemory(buf, 4096);
            int bytesReceived = recv(sock, buf, 4096, 0);
            if (bytesReceived > 0)
            {
                /*for (int i = 0; i < bytesReceived; i++)
                {
                    cout << hex << (int)buf[i];
                }*/
                std::stringstream ss;
                std::stringstream aa;
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                    ss << std::hex << (int)buf[i];

                unsigned result;
                ss >> result;
                int Number1 = result;
                cout << Number1 << "\n";

                for (int j = 2; j < 4; j++)
                    aa << std::hex << (int)buf[j];

                unsigned result2;
                aa >> result2;
                int Number2 = result2;
                cout << Number2 << "\n";
            }
```

This gives me in the console the desired number 20000 and 10000. Now how do i do this without writing for every time i want to do this, this whole part:

```
for (int j = 2; j < 4; j++)
                    aa << std::hex << (int)buf[j];

                unsigned result2;
                aa >> result2;
                int Number2 = result2;
                cout << Number2 << "\n";
```

My brain is now fried after getting to whis point from zero knowledge. Would appreciate it if someone could help me out.

Comment: If the code is working, and you are now  just trying to optimize it, then you should ask on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks, i will ask there. I just got it to work like this have been writing whis question for an hour and in between i got ideas that i tried, that is why now it is working. My original question was how to convert a char buffer to integers because i couldn't do it.

Comment: What is in your `buf`? Characters representing hex values, 0..F? Are you converting them to integers two chars at a time? How are you getting anything over 255?

Comment: I suggest searching the internet for "C++ serialize library".

Comment: @VladFeinstein in buf i am getting from a tcp stream bytes but for some reson the way i use winsock i only get chars in buf insted of 4e20 (hex) i get N (4e) and a space (20) for the first two bytes of buf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment it looks like you are getting NOT the hex characters, but in fact the binary value 2,000.

You can throw away your binary -> string -> binary conversion and get the values directly from your buffer.

Based on your code, I assume that you know you are getting 2-byte `short int` values. `recv` returns a number of bytes received, so you are getting `bytesReceived / 2` values.

You can assign them to your `result` directly, bu I suggest to use `network-to-host` function for portability.

Here is how you can do it:

```
int bytesReceived = recv(sock, buf, 4096, 0);
short int* ibuf = (short int*)buf;
for (int i = 0; i < bytesReceived / 2; ++i, ++ibuf) {
    short result = ntohs(*ibuf);
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That is exacly how i wanted it to work! I new what i was reciving but everything I tried returned as i said latters and so and not numbers. Now i will try to understand what you did. I am completly new to programming so i did not know what to do with what i was receiving.